# Docker hub connected via CLI and Docker desktop... @matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc plugin still fails to connect to docker hub on M1 Mac Air 2020

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, port, dockerhub, docker-desktop

I can only reproduce this error on my Mac Air. I have a Mac tower from 2010 that I've opencore'd to 12+ and it does not have this issue.

For the life of me, I cannot get through this error with the @matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc plugin. As you can see in the window behind my CLI, I am connected to docker hub through Docker Desktop. I can also log into docker via the CLI using `docker login`. I've already tried logging in and out using various methods.

My last suspicion is that maybe a port is natively blocked? Where would I begin trying to troubleshoot this?

[image: CLI_with_docker_desktop_behind]

Answer (score 0):

Just answering this to mention that support for Docker has been deprecated and it's recommended that users use `binary` as compiler source to compile contracts with zksolc.

You can find more info on how to compile contracts on zkSync here: https://v2-docs.zksync.io/dev/developer-guides/contracts/contracts.html

And specific information about the zksolc harhdat plugin here: https://v2-docs.zksync.io/api/hardhat/plugins.html#hardhat-zksync-solc